# Why do these two queries return different results?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have these two queries which return different row counts. When we count the rows in the 2nd query, the result would be the same as the 1st query. But it shows a different result. I need to know why.

1. `select count(*) from dual`
2. `select * from dual`

Comment: The solution to what? One is getting actual data, one is counting how many rows there are - why would they get the same results, and why would you want or expect them to?

Comment: i know this, but when we ran the query in production, the result row count from the 1st and 2nd query is different

Comment: Query 2 will return all the rows. Query 1 will return 1 row, with the count of rows.

Comment: yes, but the count must be same

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. The `dual` table only has one row (unless your DB is corrupted, of course). The first query will get a single row with the value `1`, as that is how many rows there are. The second query will get a single row with value `X`. If you are somehow seeing something different then include what you actually see in your question.

Comment: i have updated the question now, kindly read it once and let me know

Comment: So you're saying that the first query returns `1`, but the second query gives you more than one row of output? Again please edit your question to show exactly what you run and exactly what you see (as text please, not images). I suspect you've used dual as an example without checking that it has the behaviour you describe, and you're actually querying some other table - and just misinterpreting what you see. But we can't tell based on what you've said...

Comment: @paritoshverma - can you paste in the results you are seeing please, it will make the question easier to understand. It sounds like you have more than 1 row in dual, which would be a genuine problem.

Comment: I will try to provide a snapshot. but for a time being my mean is that 1st query output is 6 rows and the 2nd query output is 4 rows, for example

Comment: "for example" doesn't help us - you've shown two very specific queries, neither of which should give those results. If you're seeing unexpected results **from dual** then that could be a real problem. If it's from your own query than we have to see that query and its results (or at least *a* query and results) that actually show the behaviour. We can't explain what we can't see.

Comment: okay, I will try to provide a snapshot of the query.

Comment: @paritoshverma Does your database have a limit on the numbers of rows you can bring back in the window? A DBA may have set up that you can only bring back 10,000 rows of data for example. So the count would show everything but trying to select everything will be limited

Comment: @Jon.G, no, I have already checked with DBA team, there is no limit on pulling the data from OLTP's

Answer (score 1):

An `*` means "everything and anything". So basically this query:

```
select * from dual
```

Means "show me everything from dual".
Count literally means "count me the number of something"

```
count(*)
```

Is to count everything!

Take this as an example:

```
create table example (id int(1), ex1 varchar(15), ex2 varchar(15), ex3 varchar(15));
insert into example values(1, 'whatever11', 'whatever12', 'whatever13');
insert into example values(2, 'whatever21', 'whatever22', 'whatever23');
insert into example values(3, 'whatever31', 'whatever32', 'whatever33');
```

So a `select *` would mean to show me all the 3 rows that are inserted, with all the values:

[image]

But a `select count(*)` would mean to show me the number of rows there are. In this case, with id 1, id 2, and id 3 , there are 3 rows, so the result would be 3!

[image]

Comment: yes, but when we ran the query in production, the result count from the 1st and 2nd query is different.

Comment: it should not be same according to oracle because the execution plan is different for the above 2 query, i need to know how can i make the result same to avoid data gaps.

Comment: Read my answer in detail please! Of course it is different the result of the first and the second! They do different things! They can never show the same output. One counts the result of everything. The number of times it appears. The other (1st) shows all the data... It can never be the same @paritoshverma If the answer was useful or nice anyways, remember to upvote it

Comment: of course, you said it! It should not be the same! That is why! @paritoshverma

Comment: i know this, but when we ran the query in production, the result row count from the 1st and 2nd query is different

Comment: Well, you should post the tables in another question then. That is because we can't really help you if we cannot see WHY they are different. What you mean is that the 1st query outputs 6 rows, and the count ouputs a number 4, for example? @paritoshverma

Comment: yes, 1st query output is 6 rows and the 2nd query output is 4 rows

Comment: Okay. Until we see some code/tables, we cannot tell you what's happening... @paritoshverma It's like saying: `i am using print and it is not printing, i can't show you my code `

Comment: okay, I will try to provide a snapshot of the query.